# Controlling the hidden property of chart in SSRS 2008 having filters

Tags: reporting-services, filter, charts, hidden

I have a collection of charts in the matrix. Each of the chart displays the data based on the specific set of filters. In the current scenario, if there is no data in the chart, it displays blank. I have verified the "NoDataMessage" but no luck.

To over come this issue, I have added the Textbox with the text "No Data available" and controlling its display based on the data in the specific chart.

Each of the Charts have three filters. Can anybody please help me in formulating the expression for hidden property of the textbox? Each of the three filters check for the specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this solution so that it may help somebody in future.

1. Within the cell, add a rectangle .
2. Inside the Rectangle, add the required chart and a TextBox with the text "No Data Available".
3. Set the Hidden Property of the Chart as well as the Text box to switch the visibility as given below.

Below sample formula can be used to consider the required rows while checking the data.
Hidden Property:

```
=IIF( 
IsNothing( SUM( IIF(Fields!TypeOfSection.Value = "Win",Fields!USD_EXT_PRICE1.Value,Nothing ))) 
AND IsNothing( SUM( IIF(Fields!TypeOfSection.Value = "Win",Fields!USD_EXT_PRICE2.Value,Nothing ) ))
AND IsNothing( SUM( IIF(Fields!TypeOfSection.Value = "Win",Fields!USD_EXT_PRICE3.Value,Nothing )))
,**false,true**
)
```

Here I am checking the value of the column `TypeOfSection`, so that only required row values are considered for `SUM`.

So above formula can be used for Chart as well as Text box by interchanging the false, true values.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help other people with a similar problem...

If you are using subreports to show the charts the reason you don't see any message is SSRS hides a subreport if every dataset of the subreport doesn't return anything.

In order to show the subreport and see the "No Data Available" message you must add a dummy dataset (to the subreport) returning at least one element (i.e. SELECT 1 AS DUMMY).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subreports to show charts inside a table or matrix and want to show a "No data" message, go to the parent report, click on the subreport then open the properties window ofthe subreport and set the NoRowsMessage to your desired message. You can also apply some styles to the message like color and font.

For an very nice tutorial look to this blog post:
[SQL Server Reporting Services Tips and Tricks by Dattatrey Sindol](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3023/sql-server-reporting-services-tips-and-tricks-to-improve-the-end-user-experience/)

Comment: As of 2018, (using SSRS 2012), the color and font of the NoRowsMessage work in the report designer, but that color and font are NOT applied to the message when exported to .pdf!